# .pgpass with AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

I need to run multiple commands on an AWS Postgres RDS instance I have. I don't want to enter the password each time. I'm trying to use the [.pgpass](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-pgpass.html) file but I'm running into errors. The first time I ran into an error which said 'role "ubuntu username" does not exist'. I logged in as the postgres user and created that username. After this, the error I get said database  does not exist. I have a feeling these errors have nothing to do with trying to connect to the AWS RDS instance.

`psql --host=<awshost> --port=5432 --username=<awsrdsusername> --password --dbname=<dbname` asks for a password and then logs me in after I enter it. Now I put a file in `/home/<ubuntuusername>` called `.pgpass` which has `<awshost>:5432:<dbname>:<awsrdsusername>:<password>`. Permissions for this file are set to 0600. Now when I run `psql` from the terminal and that produces the error - `psql: FATAL:  role "<ubuntuusername>" does not exist`. These steps are as outlined on [this page](http://www.uptimemadeeasy.com/linux/navigating-postgresql-command-line-login-using-pgpass/).

Can someone help me with the steps to get a pgpass file to connect to an AWS RDS instance?

Comment: You're correct, they have nothing to do with `.pgpass`. You still have to connect using the correct connection string. *all* that the `.pgpass` file does is let `psql` look up a password. Make sure you can connect normally. Then once you can, entering the password manually, add the .pgpass file. (-1, you've been around long enough to know to include **exact text of error messages**, exact commands run, etc, not only vague descriptions).

Comment: Those weren't vague descriptions :). The only extra part I omitted was "psql: FATAL:  " which precedes the rest of the error message that I mentioned. After having tried this, I've tried uninstalling, reinstalling, and some other things too none of which worked.
I'm already able to connect manually. The only culprit I can think of is the fact that  my local username is different from my AWS RDS username.

Comment: "already able to connect manually". i.e. with a password? Adding a `.pgpass` file cannot cause an error like `role "myusername" does not exist` if the same connection works without the presence of the `.pgpass` file. Show **exact commands run**.

Comment: I've added the exact steps to the question.

Comment: Thanks. That shows what's going on. You're confused about how `.pgpass` works and switch to running `psql` without arguments when you create the `pgpass` file. This is why you should show the commands you run, exact errors, etc in your question, to avoid back-and-forth like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.pgpass` doesn't provide connection information. You seem to expect that after you create a `.pgpass` file, you can run `psql` without arguments and it'll know where to connect. That is not the case.

The hostname, port, etc you put in `.pgpass` are there so that PostgreSQL knows which line to look at when matching the connection info to find its password.

If you had to run:

```
psql -h something
```

to connect without a `.pgpass` file, you *still have to run the same thing* to connect *with* a .pgpass file.

If you run `psql` without arguments it'll connect to the local PostgreSQL (if any), using the current unix username as the postgresql username and the database to connect to. That's why you get the error you do.

If you want to change the default connection, you can use environment variables like `PGHOST`, `PGPORT`, etc, and/or [a `.pgservice.conf` file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgservice.html).

See [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) to learn more.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried `psql` with only the host name, the dbname, etc. but it (obviously) didn't work. I got the feeling that most of the manuals assumed the reader has already worked with setting up databases before.

Comment: @Codoremifa You're not the first person I've seen misunderstand `.pgpass` this way. I'll see if the manual needs clarification.